# how to show pdf from server in a Django view?

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to **show/read pdfs from server** , but getting erros. Below I have attached my view.py . Please help me to solve it

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import PDF

def pdf_view(request):
    a = PDF.objects.get(id=id)
    with open('a.pdf', 'rb') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), contenttype='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=a.pdf'
        return response
    pdf.closed
```

Comment: Please include your models.py and the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use use Django templates to show/read pdf on sever. create 'templates' folder inside your django project. inside it create a html file which contain link of you pdf.